# Vision API Web Detection Script

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to run the sample web detection script (web_detect.py) for the Vision API but am not having any luck. See [here](https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision/blob/HEAD/samples/snippets/web/web_detect.py) for more details on the script.

I've saved the script into a separate python file. I then try to run the file in my python notebook using:

```
python web_detect.py "http://www.photos-public-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/old-vw-bug-and-van.jpg"
```

... but I get the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-15-b3220db6427b>", line 1
python web_detect.py "http://www.photos-public-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/old-vw-bug-and-van.jpg"
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

See the image below for a screenshot. Any suggestions on what I'm missing and how I can get the file to run?

Thank you!

- RE

[image: ScreenShot of the errors]

Comment: Could submit it as an issue on GitHub repository, so one of the developers fix the code https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision/issues

Comment: Did my answer helped you with your problem? If yes, please consider to accept and upvote it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an **exclamation mark (!)** prior to your whole python command so that the notebook will treat it as a [command line execution](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.05-ipython-and-shell-commands.html#Shell-Commands-in-IPython).

I did test on my notebook using your input image and I got the expected response.

Command to run: `!python web_detect.py http://www.photos-public-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/old-vw-bug-and-van.jpg`

Test:
[image]

Comment: @RE Wolfe unfortunately the API does not accept an input of a webpage it can only accept images. What you can do scrape the images in the website and send a request per image.

Comment: Thank you! Have you seen any posts on how you might be able to do this at scale? That is, scrape site, upload all scraped image files to GCS, get a request per image?

Comment: @RE Wolfe You can check this [web scraping article](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-tutorial-on-scraping-images-from-the-web-using-beautifulsoup-206a7633e948) and [uploading local files to GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample). You can also post a new question as it is a separate topic from the original question so the community can share their opinion :)